# What are the similarities and differences: attend vs tend?

Tags: difference, verbs

I recognise and thus do not ask about the other [homonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph) **tend** evolved from the French 'tendre' (ODO's Definition 1), and only about [Definition 2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tend?q=tending#tend-2).

I beware of the Etymological Fallacy, but I observe that under 'Origin' is written 'shortening of **attend**'? Their usage seems identical.
For example,    Definition 1 of **tend** = 'Care for or look after; give one’s attention to'
resembles Definition 2.1 of **attend** = 'Give practical help and care to; look after' ?

By the bye, what are the phenomenons involved here called (for example,

Comment: http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED2913

Answer (score 1):

They may share one of their meanings with each other, but this does not mean they are **always** interchangeable.

> The nurse will *attend* **to** the patient.

Notice the preposition *to*, which signals the meaning of "care for."

Counterexample:

> Next year I will *attend* the symphony.

The absense of *to* here tells us the meaning is "to be at".

Answer (score 0):

You can surmise the similarities and differences of [tend def. 2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=Tend) and [attend](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=Attend).

The phenomenon, as used in some of the definitions for *tend* is an 'aph. variant of tend', where 'aph.' is short for [aphetic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/aphesis). Compare [apheresis](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/apheresis).